# Creating relationships between nodes in neo4j is extremely slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using a python script to generate and execute queries loaded from data in a CSV file. I've got a substantial amount of data that needs to be imported so speed is very important.

The problem I'm having is that merging between two nodes takes a very long time, and including the cypher to create the relations between the nodes causes a query to take around 3 seconds (for a query which takes around 100ms without).

Here's a small bit of the query I'm trying to execute:

```
MERGE (s0:Chemical{`name`: "10074-g5"})
SET s0.`name`="10074-g5"
MERGE (y0:Gene{`gene-id`: "4149"})
SET y0.`name`="MAX"
SET y0.`gene-id`="4149"
MERGE (s0)-[:INTERACTS_WITH]->(y0)
MERGE (s1:Chemical{`name`: "10074-g5"})
SET s1.`name`="10074-g5"
MERGE (y1:Gene{`gene-id`: "4149"})
SET y1.`name`="MAX"
SET y1.`gene-id`="4149"
MERGE (s1)-[:INTERACTS_WITH]->(y1)
```

Any suggestions on why this is running so slowly? I've got index's set up on Chemical->name and Gene->gene-id so I honestly don't understand why this runs so slowly.

Comment: It will help if you can [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) your query and (after expanding all elements) attach the plan to your question.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Yes this does look handy. I'm currently experimenting with `LOAD CSV` instead of using my scripts as it seems to be able to go through a lot of data extremely quickly but I'll keep this in mind if I have any more issues.

Comment: Something else I've just noticed is that I can make the query significantly quicker if I put all the merges into a separate query, and run it separately after all the nodes in my CSV file have been created. Not sure why this is but it allows my CSV file (which is a few million lines long) to be imported in less than a minute or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Most of your `SET` clauses are just setting properties to the same values they already have (as guaranteed by the preceding `MERGE` clauses).
2. The remaining `SET` clauses probably only need to be executed if the `MERGE` had created a new node. So, they should probably be preceded by `ON CREATE`.
3. You should never generate a long sequence of almost identical Cypher code. Instead, your Cypher code should use [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), and you should pass your data as parameter(s).
4. You said you have a `:Gene(id)` index, whereas your code actually requires a `:Gene(gene-id)` index.

Below is sample Cypher code that uses the `dataList` parameter (a list of maps containing the desired property values), which fixes most of the above issues. The `UNWIND` clause just "unwinds" the list into individual maps.

```
UNWIND $dataList AS d
MERGE (s:Chemical{name: d.sName})
MERGE (y:Gene{`gene-id`: d.yId})
ON CREATE SET y.name=d.yName
MERGE (s)-[:INTERACTS_WITH]->(y)
```

Comment: Most of these problems have now been solved as I'm using `LOAD CSV` which has sped up the non-relation part significantly. The creation of the relationship was still slow though. I managed to speed this up by creating the nodes first, and then building the relationships in a separate query